# Error message : Create-react-app- index.pack.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the error *index.pack.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'* I thought this was an error I made but no, i cant seem to find any errors, Here's the code for what i have got

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.3.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Also then in the app

```
import React from "react"

function App() {    
    return (
        <div>
          
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

FYI< I have installed create-react-app and deleted some of those files >
Any help would be appreciated!
Here's the error when inspected

[image]

Comment: In your index.html, <link> tags are missing the ending `/`. Should be `<link .... />`

Comment: Use `npx create-react-app name-of-my-app` to create a react project. Go to the project directory and do `npm install`. You can run the project in dev mode with `npm start` and build it with `npm build`.  [Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) is documentation how to create a react project.

Comment: sorry Chilarai that didnt work

Comment: Hi i installed create-react-app properly, now im getting that error, but dont know how to fix it @HMR

Comment: Having same problem, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by going into my index.html file (in visual studio code) and holding ctrl click on the index.pack.js link inside the tags. Visual studio code will come up with an error saying file cannot be found, would u like to create it? select yes, save and refresh your page. For me this was enough and my code worked perfectly error free.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by going into my index.html file (in visual studio code) and holding ctrl click on the index.pack.js link inside the  tags.  Visual studio code will come up with an error saying file cannot be found, would u like to create it? select yes, save and refresh your page.  For me this was enough and my code worked perfectly error free.

Comment: Also worked for me but a bit disconcerting seeing the empty file.